# Delete SQLite data in each run of the application

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to the `sqlite` database in android. I'm using `eclipce` `adt-bundle` and its simulator. In my project, I have a `sqlite` database. I need to clear data in each run of this application. Otherwise I always get the same sqlite exception again and again. So how can I clear database data in the simulator in each run?

Comment: You can delete all data from each table in your launching activity.

Comment: just increment the database version every time thats it

Answer (score 2):

In the case, you want to delete whole SQLite database from your app.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase(YOUR_DATABASE_NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is much agile, if whole database is required to be dumped. Thanks. I'd accept if i were the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Using this code, you can clear all or some specific tables. 
In you SQLiteOpenHelper Class :

```
public void deleteAllTable() {
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME_ONE);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME_TWO);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME_THREE);

    }
```

In Your Launcher activity's onCreate :

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter (context,DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME);
    db.deleteDARtable();
    db.close();
```